# Groovy script can't find JNA Class

Tags: java, groovy, jna

I want to write event in Windows and only groovy is supported on my application.

I wrote short code to test, but I got the following exception always :

```
Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Advapi32
    at ProcessStateHandler.registerEventSource(test.groovy:32)
    at ProcessStateHandler.main(test.groovy:23)
```

Test code is like this :

```
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Advapi32
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Advapi32Util
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Win32Exception
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT.HANDLE
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinReg

import com.sun.jna.Native
import com.sun.jna.Library
import com.sun.jna.Platform
import com.sun.jna.Pointer



public class ProcessStateHandler {
    def APPLICATION_EVENT_LOG_REGISTRY = "SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\EventLog\\Application"
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        println "First groovy test"
        CLibrary.INSTANCE.printf("Hello, World\n")

        ProcessStateHandler processStateHandler = new ProcessStateHandler()
        processStateHandler.registerEventSource("", "SourceForTest")
    }

    private void registerEventSource(String server, String source) {

        source = source.trim()

        assert Advapi32 
//        assert Advapi32.INSTANCE         
        HANDLE eventHandle = Advapi32.INSTANCE.RegisterEventSource(server, source)
    }
}


public interface CLibrary extends Library {
    CLibrary INSTANCE = (CLibrary) Native.loadLibrary((Platform.isWindows() ? 'msvcrt' : 'c'), CLibrary.class)

    void printf(String format, Object... args)
}
```

In my guess, groovy does not support variables in Interface. Advapi32 interface is declared like this.

```
public interface Advapi32 extends StdCallLibrary {
    Advapi32 INSTANCE = (Advapi32) Native.loadLibrary("Advapi32",
            Advapi32.class, W32APIOptions.UNICODE_OPTIONS);
   /* blah 
      blah 
      blah */
}
```

How do I access INSTANCE or call method in Advapi32 interface?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, my test was wrong.

When i test the codes in Eclipse, there is no problem. 
GroovyConsole may have class loader problem.